# Switching to another shell without copying environment variables

Tags: zsh, exec

From tcsh, if I try:

```
exec /home/path/to/my/zsh
```

it works (I enter a Zsh shell)

but if I try

```
exec -c /home/path/to/my/zsh
```

I get:

```
-c Command not found
```

How do I switch to my Zsh shell and start it from a "blank slate"? (i.e. with no environment variables carried over from `tcsh` ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to do that, but you can do:

```
exec env -i /home/path/to/my/zsh
```

Probably many things won't work properly as you'll be missing some essential environment variables like `$PATH`, `$HOME` or `$TERM`.

If you want to whitelist a few variables and remove the rest:

```
exec env -i HOME="$HOME" TERM="$TERM" /home/path/to/my/zsh
```

If you want to restore the environment at the time `tcsh` was started, you could insert this to the very beginning of `~/.tcshrc`:

```
sh -c 'export -p' > ~/.initial-env
```

And then do something like:

```
exec env -i sh -c ". $HOME/.initial-env; exec /path/to/zsh"
```

That is save the environment when `tcsh` starts and restore it when you execute zsh.

If what you want is change your shell to `zsh` while you don't have to possibility to do a `chsh` (or `zsh` is not installed or the one installed is 20 years old), (brings back memory from over 15 years ago (gosh!) when I was in the exact same situation (though with `csh` instead of `tcsh`)), you can replace the content of your `~/.login` with:

```
setenv SHELL /path/to/zsh
exec $SHELL -l
```

And remove your `.tcshrc`

Setting `$SHELL` specifies your shell *preference* (that is what applications like `xterm` or `vi`... will start when they need to start a shell for you).

Putting it in your `~/.login` should ensure it's only done once. Hopefully, no more `tcsh` would be started later on during your login session since you've changed `$SHELL`. It shouldn't matter whether you put your environment variable definitions in `~/.login` or `~/.zprofile` or `~/.profile`. It's up to you.

Test with `tcsh -l` before logging out.

Comment: Thanks! To answer your first question. I don't have admin privileges to change my default shell, and I would like to specify my env. variables directly in my `.zshrc`, since Zsh is the only interactive shell that I use. Does my approach to this problem make sense?

Comment: @user815423426 You don't need, and indeed should not, remove environment variables. Just do `exec /home/path/to/my/zsh` or rather `exec /home/path/to/my/zsh -l` to make zsh load `~/.zprofile`. If there's some environment variable you don't want, unset it in your `.zprofile`.